# get next sequence value Oracle using Ado.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have tried various forms of the following method to get the next sequence value from an Oracle DB in my asp.net app.  The sql statement works fine in Toad (11g).  The sql statement includes "Select ... myschema.mySeq.nextval ... from dual.  But the error I receive when I get to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() -- the error is:

> >
>   Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   <<

Authentication is a very big deal at the place where I am at.  Is this a data Access problem or is something incorrect with my method (below)?  If something is incorrect with the code below what is the correction I need to make?  Note: the app (big app) has hundreds of calls to SPs (which all work fine), so I basically copied the connection string code and used a constant (like they do throughout the app).  If I use an SP this works, but I want to not use an SP just straight forward Ado.Net.  What is the fix?

```
public int getNextPositionSequence(string userSeq)
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(DaoHelper.GetConnectionString("AuthenticatedOracleConnectionString"));
    conn.Open();
    conn.ClientId = userSeq;
    string sql = "SELECT ddtms.position_seq.nextval from dual";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
    object s = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //<<<--- crashes here

    conn.Close();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Check your connection string. Make sure you are connecting to the correct server, correct schema, and that your user has access to the appropriate schema objects you want to query.

Comment: The user connected to the database could only have execute SP rights and no sequence (select) access rights

Comment: Igor AND JeroenHeier are correct.  Also I believe that you need to remove ddtms.  I tried specifying the schema like you did but that didn't work for me.  So I believe that you need to make sure you have the correct rights and then remove "ddtms." from your query.

Comment: Thank you all for replies.  I guess it is a data access issue.  And, if I don't have the rights except for the SPs then the end users probably don't either, so I guess I will stick with the SPs.  As for removing the schema from the sql, I tried that in toad, and it did not work.  Either way, I guess I will just add another SP to the thousands that we already have in this DB.  Many thanks All.

Comment: I do this for my application, so it is possible.  You wouldn't use an end users credentials to do this operation.  You would use a common user. Either the table owner or someone who has full permissions on the owners tables.   As a test, you should use the credentials for the table owner.  If that works then your db user doesn't have enough permissions.